# Melómano y cinéfilo ¿Por qué se forman con sufijos diferentes?

Tags: rae, sufijos

**Melómano** y **cinéfilo** ¿Por qué se forman con sufijos diferentes? ¿De dónde proviene el sufijo -filo? El Diccionario de la Real Academia Española, en cuanto a los que les gusta la música les llama fanáticos (melómanos) y a los que les gusta el cine aficionados (cinéfilos). ¿Existe algún término "más suave" para los que les guste la música sin llamarlos **fanáticos**?

Answer (score 7):

Como ya ha contestado @bluish,

**-filo** proviene del griego antiguo que expresa una *clase de amor* o *inclinación hacia* algo.

**-mano** (también) proviene del griego antiguo, y expresa una *clase de locura* hacia algo.

Por otro lado, en línea con lo que comenta @leonbloy, las elecciones de los prefijos y sufijos no siempre siguen una regla fija. Un ejemplo sencillo sería:

**filosofía**, que significa "amor a la sabiduría" (filos  -> amor, sofía -> sabiduría)

**bibliofilia**, que significa "amor a los libros" (biblio -> libro, filia -> amor)

Como ves, el orden es invertido aunque el sufijo, en un caso, y prefijo, en el otro, quieren dar el mismo significado a la palabra. Otro ejemplo de esta variedad en la interpretación de sufijos sería:

**bibliofilia**, como comentaba antes (también valdría *cinéfilo* como decías)

**zoofilia**, que a pesar de que signifique "amor a los animales" (zoo -> animales, filia -> amor) tiene una connotación bastante diferente a la de la expresada por *bibliofilia* en relación a los libros, la connotación de atracción sexual por animales.

Teniendo esto en cuenta, y a pesar de que en general el sujifo **-mania** tenga la connotación de *locura insana* o *deseo descontrolado* por algo, creo que en el caso de la melomanía (melo -> canción) se ha querido expresar la *profunda pasión* por la música, no queriendo tener una connotación negativa, sino todo lo contrario. En este sentido sí creo que cuando se acuñó el término, se le quiso dar ese sentido, buscando tal vez un sufijo que expresara algo más fuerte que *-filia*.

Buscando un poco por internet, encontré esta etimología, que a pesar de no encontrar fuentes que la verificaran, me parece que expresa un poco lo que entiendo de esa palabra:

> Etimología: del francés *mélomane*, acuñado hacia 1781 por el dramaturgo y músico francés Pierre-Augustin Caron de Beaumarchais a partir de *mélo-*, del griego antiguo μελο-, forma combinatoria de μέλος (mélos), "canción, tonada", de origen incierto; y *-mane*, del griego antiguo -μανής (manés), forma adjetiva de μανία (manía), "pasión, entusiasmo, locura", de μαίνομαι (maínomai), "delirar", del protoindoeuropeo *mn̥yo-, en última instancia de *men-, "pensar".

En resumen, e intentando contestar a tu última pregunta, creo que el problema que comentas de esas palabras es la forma en que uno la entiende. *Fanático* y *melómano* no tienen porque tener una connotación negativa, cuando te refieres a algo positivo, como la música. Yo no conozco otra palabra que defina el "*amor a la música*", como la buscas. En mi opinión, estas palabras son perfectamente válidas para ello.

Comment: A mí me convence que se use melómano por una cierta asociación entre pasión y locura.
Sin embargo, también sospecho que tiene más bien que ver con la etimología. El primer usuario de la palabra (según http://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/mel%C3%B3mano) quizá quería proporcionar un efecto mayor que "filos", y por eso utilizó "manos".
Por otro lado, mira la etimología de ese -manos, no está cerrado el significado a locura, si no que incluye también entusiasmo, pasión...

Answer (score 5):

**-filo** viene de *filia* (griego) que es una especie de amor hacia algo.

**-mano** viene de *manía* (griego) que es una especie de locura hacia algo (es más fuerte).

Además de **melómano** (que [parece estar vinculado con la ópera](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melomane)) podrías utilizar [**musicómano**](http://dle.rae.es/musicoman%C3%ADa). Sin embargo, parece ser que no hay **musicófilo**, que resultaría más suave. ¡En el peor de los casos estarías creando un neologismo! ;)

Comment: Las terminaciones no explican porque se use locura para música y aficionado para los amantes del cine.

Comment: Imagino que porque el comportamiento de los fans acérrimos de la música ante sus ídolos suele ser más exacerbado que el de los fans del cine.

Comment: *Melómano* is definietly not specifically related to opera, but to music. That's a false cognate with Italian. The meaning in Spanish coincides with the use is given to *melòmane* in French, to (*Меломан*)[http://www.lingvo-online.ru/ru/Translate/en-ru/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD ] in Russian, with [melomaniac in English](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/melomaniac). There is no reference to opera in that languages. There is no reference to opera in Spanish either. Altough etymologically it could be rather related to singing, that meaning is no longer understood.

Answer (score 2):

El sufijo -filo viene del griego.

Un sufijo relacionado es -filia.  Ver el comentario en Wikipedia.

http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filia

Comment: Gracias, hasta allí vamos bien vamos bien. Una de las preguntas esta respondida sin embargo, que da el resto. ¿Por que entonces se usa un término que califica patológico el gusto por la música? ¿Y por qué a los que les gusta el cine no los ve como enfermos?

Comment: Creo que eso ya involucra cosas más complejas, como por ejemplo la ética o como decir que esta bien y que esta mal, hay gente que dice que la sociedad impone esto. El cine de alguna manera es la vida de muchos, la música también, ambos son arte, depende el grado de fanatismo de algo. Por ejemplo las cosas no son malas sino lo que se hace con ellas, imagina un coche, por si solo no es malo, pero si manejas irresponsablemente si es malo... no sé si me de a entender. Y lo demás sale por etimologias.

Comment: @ErnestoMarrero: Yo creo que la preferencia por un sufijo en uno y otro caso es más bien arbitraria, quizás los hablantes se decanten por una u otra debido a cuestiones de sonoridad ("melómano" suena bien, simplemente). En general se prefiere "filo" (audiófilo).